# Use decades on the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a graph like so:

[image]I use this code to format my x-axis

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))
```

But now I have a lot of years and I want to use decades only on the x-axis: 1970 1980 1990 2000 and so on. How can I acheive this?

Comment: Is your x data *evenly spaced*? `x[2]-x[1] == x[3]-x[2] == x[n]-x[n-1]`?

Answer (score 1):

https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.YearLocator

`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.dates.YearLocator(10))`

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set the x-ticks:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 10.0))
```